# How can I perform many of Fisher's exact tests for a big number of genes?

Tags: r, p-value

I would like to do a Fisher's exact test 2x2 for each gene on my list (see picture) to statistically check if there are any differences in frequencies, for each gene, between the two compared groups (i.e., M1 and M2). Due to the big number of genes, I can't mount manually a contingency table for each one and calculate the Fischer test individually. Could you please inform me about the R codes to calculate the Fisher's p-value for each of the genes in an easier and faster way?

[Example_My List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVJ18.png)

```
data=structure(list(M1 = c(0.87, 0.93, 0.8, 0.53, 0.27, 0.53, 0.93, 
0.6, 0.93, 0.8, 1, 0.93, 0.87, 0.73, 1, 0.47, 1, 0.87, 0.47, 
0.27), M2 = c(0.76, 0.71, 0.19, 0.52, 0.33, 0.67, 0.9, 0.71, 
0.81, 1, 0.76, 0.14, 0.9, 1, 0.9, 0.81, 0.95, 0.43, 0.86, 0.14
)), row.names = c("Phvul.001G002900", "Phvul.001G003000", "Phvul.001G006300", 
"Phvul.001G007400", "Phvul.001G008300", "Phvul.001G009600", "Phvul.001G011300", 
"Phvul.001G012300", "Phvul.001G012700", "Phvul.001G012800", "Phvul.001G013200", 
"Phvul.001G013400", "Phvul.001G015000", "Phvul.001G016600", "Phvul.001G018600", 
"Phvul.001G021550", "Phvul.001G024300", "Phvul.001G025300", "Phvul.001G027900", 
"Phvul.001G030400"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: 1) Those are not frequencies. 2) And you want to have all 2x2 tables that can be made from those rows? 3) Images are not the best way of posting code or data, can you post the output of `dput(head(df, 20))` in the question, please?

Comment: Dear @RuiBarradas I am sorry, I can not find the way to upload the CSV input file. The picture is a screenshot of my CSV: column A is a list of 5271 genes, while columns B and C are the frequencies for each gene in the sub-populations M1 and M2, respectively. I am working with PAV (presence/absence variation), so I calculated the presence frequencies for each gene within each sub-population.  Now I would like to calculate the Fisher's exact test 2X2 for each row. I hope I have explained well. Thanks

Comment: Can't you read the file into a R session? We only need a small number of its rows, like the 20 rows the command in my previous comment says.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I updated the question adding the information you have asked me. Is it ok now?

Comment: Columns M1 and M2 are not frequencies data, I am not seeing how you can form contigency tables from them. Can you give an example of contingency tables, created for a couple of genes, not each one?

Comment: @RuiBarradas sorry for the confusion. I realized that, instead of analyzing a 2x2 matrix, I need to calculate Fisher's exact test for each row in order to see if there are differences statistically relevant between M1 and M2 for each gene (for instance, I would like to compare 0.86 with 0.76 (first row); 0.93 vs 0.71 (second row) and so on...). I would like to share with you the original count behind these frequencies values, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You seem to want a paired-samples t-test. `t.test(data$M1, data$M2, paired = TRUE)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas If I run the command t.test(data$M1, data$M2, paired = TRUE) I get this output: Paired t-test

data:  Data$M1 and Data$M2
t = 1.1076, df = 5270, p-value = 0.2681
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.003308581  0.011902776
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
            0.004297097

Comment: @RuiBarradas However, I need a p-value for each gene instead of one overall p-value. How can I do that? Do I have to create a loop in the r code maybe?

Comment: I still don't understand how can you have a contingency table if you only have one gene (at a time). If the data is too big to post contigency tables for each gene, post an example of one or two tables, also using `dput(tbl)`. And yes, you can loop through the table with `apply` or `for` statements.